# I keep cancelling my edit rejects!

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Every now and again on a Stack Exchange site, I run across an edit that I want to reject with a custom reject message. So the typical procedure kicks in:

- click reject
- select custom message
- focus the text area
- type
  (and this is where muscle memory kicks in:)
- **hit tab, hit enter**

The box goes away, but I am perplexed. The suggested edit review post is still there. It takes me a while to realise what happened: rather than jumping to *reject* (or whatever it’s called; I don’t get too many suggested edits on the sites I frequent) the first tab stop is *cancel!* So on we go:

- swear
- click reject again
- select custom message again
- focus the text area again
- try to remember what I typed, type somthing similar
- hit tab **only just remember not to hit enter**
- use the mouse to navigate to the correct button
- reject the edit.

Could the Stack Exchange team please modify this overly long workflow so that all the bullet points between *hit tab, hit enter* and *reject the edit* are removed; i.e. could the first ‘tab stop’ after the text box please be *perform that action* rather than *cancel?*

(If this is designed to prevent overly rash rejections it doesn’t fulfil its intention: if I actually made an effort to type a reject reason I have obviously thought everything through and know what I’m doing.)

(For some reason, mod notice flags don’t work like this; tab+enter there posts the flag. Thus, I see no reason why it doesn’t work for edit rejects.)

Comment: If the sites have successfully trolled you, I can sleep better at night.